# How can I correctly check that integer underflow and overflow will not happen before subtraction?

Tags: c++, integer, subtraction, integer-overflow

I'm currently working on a safe integer library for C++. I've come across some issues when implementing subtraction.

Here's what I start with:

```
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename I>
class safe_int
{
    I val;

public:
    typedef I value_type;
    static constexpr I max = std::numeric_limits<I>::max();
    static constexpr I min = std::numeric_limits<I>::min();

    safe_int(I i) : val { i } { };

    safe_int &operator+=(I rhs)
    {
        if( val > 0 && rhs > max - val )
            throw std::overflow_error("");
        else if( val < 0 && rhs < min - val )
            throw std::underflow_error("");

        val += rhs;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I first attempted to write `operator-=` like this:

```
safe_int &operator-=(I rhs)
{
    return operator+=(-rhs);
}
```

but obviously this will fail with input of `-0x80000000` on a two's complement system.

I then attempted to do it like this:

```
safe_int &operator-=(I rhs)
{
    if(rhs < -max)
        throw std::overflow_error("");

    return operator+=(-rhs);
}
```

But this doesn't work for anything less than `0` (e.x. `-1 - -0x80000000` should be `0x7fffffff` but instead reports overflow).

I then tried this:

```
safe_int &operator-=(I rhs)
{
    if( rhs < -max && val > 0 )
        throw std::overflow_error("");

    return operator+=(-rhs);
}
```

But now even though it correctly catches a case where overflow would occur, it itself causes overflow in a valid case (e.x. `-1 - -0x80000000`, where `- -0x80000000` overflows).

At this point I believe that there's no way to reuse code from the addition while catching all of the corner cases. Therefore, I should probably write different code for the subtraction.

How can I correctly check that integer overflow will not happen before subtraction?

Here's a little test program:

```
int main(void)
{
    safe_int<int> i = -1;

    i -= -2147483648;

    return 0;
}
```

Assume no particular size of integer. Do not rely on undefined behavior.

Comment: there are special instructions (addition, subtraction, multiplication) that inform about overflow - but I doubt that there are any portable ones. you can try to look for them.

Comment: @ALX23z As you can tell I'm not using assembly nor am I adding before I check for overflow. I intend this to be entirely portable.

Comment: I know this is besides the point, but have you checked https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/safe_numerics ?

Comment: @Tarc I don't use Boost. It's a pain to install and brings in a huge library to something that would otherwise be simple.

Comment: Yeah, but at least it is curated and, I think, Safe Numerics is intended to be portable. Maybe it is worth reading to see the techniques the author made use of.

Comment: @S.S.Anne the problem is that then the computations will become slow and non-optimizable. It easier and faster to wrap the computation in a bigger integer if one fears overflow.

Comment: @ALX23z I can't necessarily guarantee a bigger integer, though. I may be trying to multiply `long long` (which is a valid template parameter) and I wouldn't have any option for a bigger integer.

Comment: @S.S.Anne only in `long long` there might actually be a problem which overflows at a ridiculously large number. But OK. Say, an overflow was detected. What now? Quit program? How do you envision usage of the library?

Comment: @ALX23z Quit program. I'm not going to try to recover from an error that can't really be recovered from. I'm just going to leave it to manual intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class I>
bool valid_add( I lhs, I rhs ) {
  static constexpr I max = std::numeric_limits<I>::max();
  static constexpr I min = std::numeric_limits<I>::min();

  if( rhs > 0 && lhs > max - rhs ) return false;
  if( rhs < 0 && lhs < min - rhs ) return false;

  return true;
}
template<class I>
bool valid_subtract( I lhs, I rhs ) {
  static constexpr I max = std::numeric_limits<I>::max();
  static constexpr I min = std::numeric_limits<I>::min();

  if ((rhs < 0) && (lhs > max + rhs)) return false;
  if ((rhs > 0) && (lhs < min + rhs)) return false;

  return true;
}
```

note that the two functions are basically asking the same question.  First we ask "what direction will `rhs` move our result from `lhs`".  Then we check if `lhs` is "far enough away" from the `min` or `max` in that direction.

In your code simply inject:

```
if (!valid_add(val, rhs))
   throw "whatever";
```

and

```
if (!valid_subtract(val, rhs))
   throw "whatever";
```

you'll need to change this code if not using it on integral types.  On floating point types, there are more complications.

After you check that the operation is valid, **simply do it**.  Don't call another function.

Comment: The first is underflow and the second is overflow, correct?

Comment: @S.S.Anne I have 4 different bounds checks in the above code, I'm not certain what you mean by first or second.  Passing max is overflow, passing min is underflow, in a sense.

Comment: I meant the second function, that checks subtraction.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Then no.  Passing max is overflow, not underflow.  Rearrange `lhs > max + rhs` to be `lhs - rhs > max` to see the (unsafe, but mathematically equivalent) version of the test.